# sed + add char before each number

Tags: regex, sed

I want to add a "/" before each number using `sed`:

```
    echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  | sed 's/[ ^]*/&\//g'

    /1 /2 /3 /4 /5 /6 /7/
```

When I use this syntax, why do I get the "/" after 7? How can I fix my `sed` syntax in order to get this:

```
    /1 /2 /3 /4 /5 /6 /7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
echo '1 2 3 4 5 6 7' | sed 's|\w\+|/&|g'
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

to fix it: prepend the slash before the beginning of a number (i use the `:`to separate pattern and replacement instead of `/`, no need to escape the slash then)

```
 % echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 | sed 's:\([1-9]\+\):/\1:g'
```

the problem of your command is, that you use the `*`to match either `space` or a carret `^`. and not just one of them but any number of them, including 0. that matches at the end of the line (after the 7) as well (and luckily for you also at the beginning).

to make this work with either word (aka nonspace) use this:

```
 % echo ha hu 1 2 ho | sed 's:[^ ]\+:/&:g'
```

Comment: I get /1 /2 /3 /4 /5 /6 /71 (why 1 number after 7?)

Comment: you get 1 because i added a 1 to the last 7 to give you a pattern that works on any integer, not only single digits.

Comment: but I dont want 1 after 7

Comment: any way this is numbers example  could  be words and your sed fit for numbers

Comment: then a) be more specific in your question and b) replace "71" with "7" by pure imagination.

Comment: The caret inside square brackets in `[ ^]` would match a literal caret rather than the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: or the opposite of the char after it (but you know that), iirc. but in this case you are right.

Comment: Yes, if it was `[^ ]` but I specified "in `[ ^]`". Just so we're clear ;).